# Saving Array Variable From Oracle Query

Tags: php, function

I am creating a function that extract all rows from a column with parameters and returning them as an array. So when user needed to call that function to fill in a select dropdown, the function will read from several parameters and display them in an array. but im getting an error. please help me

my function is ,

```
function QueryParam($conn, $data, $table){
    static $stmt = array();

    $firstParam = TRUE;

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table;

        foreach ($data as $key => $value){
            if ($firstParam){
                $firstParam = FALSE;
                $query .= ' WHERE ';
            } else {
                $query .= ' AND ';
            }
            $query .= "$key = :b$key";
        }

    $queryhash = md5($query);

    if (is_null($stmt[$queryhash])) {
        $stmt[$queryhash] = oci_parse($conn, $query);   
    }

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        oci_bind_by_name($firstStmt[$queryhash], ":b$key", $data[$key], -1);
    }
    oci_execute($stmt[$queryhash], OCI_DEFAULT);
    return oci_fetch_array($stmt[$queryhash], OCI_ASSOC);
}
```

And I am calling that function

```
$test = QueryParam($conn, "PROJECT_NAME = LPIEXTMILLHOUSE", "MASTER_DRAWING");
print_r($test);
```

The errors I am getting are,

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesProjectManagement\lib\GeneralFunction.php on line 47

Notice: Undefined index: a8961369da6bc0fd60c573021c17ddc2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesProjectManagement\lib\GeneralFunction.php on line 59

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesProjectManagement\lib\GeneralFunction.php on line 63
Array ( [HEAD_MARK] => IGG-SW-CP1 [ENTRY_DATE] => 18-SEP-14 [COMP_TYPE] => CANOPY [WEIGHT] => 35.8 [SURFACE] => 2 [PROFILE] => L50*50*5 [PROJECT_NAME] => SUGARWHOUSE [LENGTH] => 3040 [TOTAL_QTY] => 1 [SUBCONT_STATUS] => ASSIGNED [DWG_STATUS] => ACTIVE [REV] => 0 [DISTRIBUTION_COUNT] => 1 )
```

The result only returning 1 row of array, the result should be more than 1 row